# replace {text} in echo with another string

Tags: php

I am not sure what this is called, so sorry if the title is confusing.

In my database i have a table called scripts.

In this i have the column 'script' which is LongText.

I am then echoing it in a php file.

In the script (LONGTEXT) it contains the text {name}.

For example : Hello, this is {name} calling.

Lets say on the php file i have

```
$username = "Jack";
```

is there a way of replacing {name} with "Jack"? automatically.

thanks

Comment: I guess there must be a ton of duplicate questions on SF. Have you searched with keywords like "string replace" ?

Comment: Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). For example `echo str_replace('{name}', $username, $script)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newText = str_replace('{name}', $username, $data['text']);
```

Check this [PHP: str_replace - Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: You have the parameters all mixed up.